# Is it possible to configure a custom DataService<T> to allow impersonation?

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata, impersonation

On a "standard" WCF service I'd simply mark up the operation methods with:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
```

But with my data service, I get an InvalidOperationException as soon as the DataServiceHost is opened:

```
The service operation 'ProcessRequestForMessage' that belongs to the contract with the 'IRequestHandler' name and the 'http://tempuri.org/' namespace does not allow impersonation.
```

How do I mark 'ProcessRequestForMessage' to allow impersonation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the behavior the following:

```
<behavior>
  <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" />
  <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" impersonateOnSerializingReply="true" />
</behavior>
```

See also [WCF Data Service with WIF 4.5; Principal not set for POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384002/wcf-data-service-with-wif-4-5-principal-not-set-for-post-requests)

Comment: Is this 4.5 only? We're using 4.0