# WCF Data Service with WIF 4.5; Principal not set for POST requests

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wif, claims-based-identity

After following Dominick Baier's Pluralsight courses and blogs around WIF 4.5, I'm still stuck with problem that I'm unable to resolve. I am using WCF Data Services with claims based authorization using WIF 4.5.

I have my `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` and `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` set up in the web.config:

```
<section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
...
<system.identityModel>
<identityConfiguration>
    <claimsAuthenticationManager type="Magnum.WCFDataService.ClaimsTransformer, Magnum.WCFDataService" />
    <claimsAuthorizationManager type="Magnum.WCFDataService.AuthorizationManager, Magnum.WCFDataService" />
</identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

Here are the contents of my AuthorizationManager:

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var action = context.Action.First();

        if (action.Type.Equals(ClaimPermission.ActionType))
        {
            var resource = context.Resource.First();
            return context.Principal.HasClaim(resource.Value, action.Value);
        }

        return base.CheckAccess(context);
    }
}
```

The first problem I encountered was that WCF was automatically calling my `AuthorizationManager` for every request and passing in the http verb for the action and the URL for the resource, this was useless as I wanted to manually determine when the claims were called using the query and change interceptors provided by data services. That's where I found Dominick's [explanation](http://leastprivilege.com/2011/05/03/improving-wifs-claims-based-authorization-part-1/) of the problem suggesting to write a custom class and attribute to replace `ClaimsPrincipalPermission`. That went fine, the attribute is on the change and query interceptor and calls my `AuthorizationManager` a second time with my custom URI.

Now, the problem is, for GET requests, it works without a hitch. The `AuthorizationManager` gets called once by WCF which I ignore and a second time using my attribute which I handle. However, for POST requests (anytime I have a change interceptor), when the `AuthorizationManager` is called a second time with my URI, the principal on the context is a `GenericPrincipal` rather than a `ClaimsPrincipal` and doesn't contain my claims to check.

How can I ensure that I always get my `ClaimsPrincipal` which is generated from my ClaimsTransformer (ClaimsAuthenticationManager) everytime the `AuthorizationManager` is called?

**Further information**
After some intensive Googling, I've narrowed the problem down. I'm only seeing the GenericPrincipal if I use the SaveChangesOptions.Batch when calling the SaveChanges method from my client. If I do not send a batch update, I get a ClaimsPrincipal back as normal. So, new question; How do I retain the ClaimsPrincipal for batch updates?

I found some information on an MSDN thread (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35eb817d-363c-4a94-b9eb-351cd0d8567f/batch-update-and-impersonation-current-user) stating that I need to use the following in my web.config:

```
<serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" impersonateOnSerializingReply="true" />
```

but now I am getting the following error:

```
The service operation 'ProcessRequestForMessage' that belongs to the contract with the 'IRequestHandler' name and the 'http://tempuri.org/' namespace does not allow impersonation.
```

Comment: @leastprivilege Would you have a few moments to offer your advice on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, this is the correct configuration to ensure batch requests work correctly with WIF 4.5 using a WCF Data Service

```
<behavior>
  <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" />
  <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" impersonateOnSerializingReply="true" />
</behavior>
```